# Each iterates elements outside defined selector

Tags: jquery

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate my troubles: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zxpbhaj/2/)

My problem is, that it seems to also include element outside of my table. As i see it, it should only iterate button and input elements inside my table with id "uddannelse" ..

**My iteration code:**

```
$(function () {        
        $('#uddannelse input, button').each(function(index, element) 
        {                                           
            alert($(this).attr("type") + "id= "+$(this).attr("id") ); 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this :

```
$(function () {        
        $('#uddannelse input, #uddannelse button').each(function(index, element) 
        {                                           
            alert($(this).attr("type") + "id= "+$(this).attr("id") ); 
        }); 
    });
```

This means you are targetting the input and button elements inside the table with id 'uddannelse'.

P.S : Your fiddler link almost killed me with those alert statements ;)

Comment: yeah i thought about it right after i posted it. You are lucky i removed 8 rows from the table :)  .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The selector `$("#uddannelse input, button")` selects all the `input` elements that are inside `#uddannelse`, but the `button` elements are not restricted. You can use

```
$("#uddannelse").find("input, button")
```

to restrict both of them to within `#uddannelse`.

Answer (score 1):

This should help; `$('#uddannelse input, #uddannelse button')`, because then you target both the input and the button inside `#uddannelse`, instead of input inside it, but all buttons.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/m2y0r7o5/)